RET_CHECK failure: Output tensor range is required
When I run the code, I got this error. Also, I already installed the dependencies needed like cvzone and mediapipe, but it is still error.
Can someone help me with this or know what's the problem?
import cv2
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Video.mp4')

detector = PoseDetector()
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findPose(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chashanefaith.babanto/Desktop/CRYSTHEL/Motion Capture/MotionCap.py", line 6, in <module>
    detector = PoseDetector()
  File "/Users/chashanefaith.babanto/Desktop/CRYSTHEL/Motion Capture/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cvzone/PoseModule.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose(static_image_mode=self.staticMode,
  File "/Users/chashanefaith.babanto/Desktop/CRYSTHEL/Motion Capture/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solutions/pose.py", line 146, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/chashanefaith.babanto/Desktop/CRYSTHEL/Motion Capture/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._graph = calculator_graph.CalculatorGraph(
RuntimeError: ValidatedGraphConfig Initialization failed.
ImageToTensorCalculator: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_calculator.cc:144) ValidateOptionOutputDims(options) returned INTERNAL: ; RET_CHECK failure (./mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_utils.h:136) options.has_output_tensor_float_range() || options.has_output_tensor_int_range() || options.has_output_tensor_uint_range()Output tensor range is required. 
InferenceCalculatorCpu: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/inference_calculator_cpu.cc:63) !options.model_path().empty() ^ kSideInModel(cc).IsConnected()Either model as side packet or model path in options is required.
SplitDetectionVectorCalculator: The number of output streams should match the number of ranges specified in the CalculatorOptions.
ImageToTensorCalculator: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_calculator.cc:144) ValidateOptionOutputDims(options) returned INTERNAL: ; RET_CHECK failure (./mediapipe/calculators/tensor/image_to_tensor_utils.h:136) options.has_output_tensor_float_range() || options.has_output_tensor_int_range() || options.has_output_tensor_uint_range()Output tensor range is required. 
ConstantSidePacketCalculator: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/core/constant_side_packet_calculator.cc:64) (cc->OutputSidePackets().NumEntries(kPacketTag))==(options.packet_size())Number of output side packets has to be same as number of packets configured in options.
ConstantSidePacketCalculator: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/core/constant_side_packet_calculator.cc:64) (cc->OutputSidePackets().NumEntries(kPacketTag))==(options.packet_size())Number of output side packets has to be same as number of packets configured in options.
ConstantSidePacketCalculator: ; RET_CHECK failure (mediapipe/calculators/core/constant_side_packet_calculator.cc:64) (cc->OutputSidePackets().NumEntries(kPacketTag))==(options.packet_size())Number of output side packets has to be same as number of packets configured in options.
SplitTensorVectorCalculator: The number of output streams should match the number of ranges specified in the CalculatorOptions.
SplitNormalizedLandmarkListCalculator: The number of output streams should match the number of ranges specified in the CalculatorOptions.
SplitLandmarkListCalculator: The number of output streams should match the number of ranges specified in the CalculatorOptions.


I got the same problem!!!! I solved it by installing the old version of mediapipe(0.10.0).
